# Why is this object not being saved in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

As an exercise, I'm trying to use the rails-api gem to build an API but 
I can't understand what's the problem with that code.
Are there mistakes I didn't see ?
I'm using rails 4.2.4

**Model :**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 32 }
  validates :content, :presence => true, length: { minimum: 60, maximum: 160 }

end
```

**Controller :**

```
class TodosController < ActionController::API


  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    if @todo.valid?
      if @todo.save
        render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo
      else
        render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end


  private

    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

**Spec :**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TodosController, type: :controller do

  describe "#create" do
    context "when JSON format" do
      describe "#create" do
        subject{ 
          post :create, { 
            :format => :json,
            :todo => { 
              :title => 'the title',
              :content => 'the content which is bigger than the title' 
            } 
          }
        }
        its(:status) { should == 200 } # OK

        it "saves the todo" do
          subject
          Todo.all.count.should == 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Error running this command "rspec spec/" :**

```
F................

Failures:

1) TodosController#create when JSON format #create saves the todo
   Failure/Error: Todo.all.count.should == 1

     expected: 1
          got: 0 (using ==)
   # ./spec/controllers/todos_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: check the errors you're rendering? :)

Comment: my problem is solved, but I'm curious how can I check the errors please?

Comment: @Neimad971 you can use the `byebug` gem and stop execution wherever you call it and debug your code.

Comment: thank you @miligraf, I'll check this out in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In your create method, if the model is not valid then the code will never reach the `render` statements.  In that case, rails will assume the status was `:ok` and render the default template.

Try refactoring your code so it will always hit either case.

```
def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

  if @todo.save # will be false if the save didn't work
    render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo
  else
    render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: you gave an insight : it because of content's length in spec (42 chars and should be minimum 60 according my validation).

Comment: is "if @object.valid? good pattern in the create method ? Thank you for your insight

Comment: As always, depends on your needs.  My office tends to use `if @object.save` and `if @object.update` since those will fail or pass depending on if the object is valid or not anyways.